# Data frame arrange/rearrange and removing duplicate columns

Tags: r, join, dataframe, duplicates

## R Data Set

```
x <- data.frame(term = c("A", "B", "C"))
x$points <- list(
  data.frame(title=c("Iliad", "Odyssey"), value=c(-1194, -800)),
  data.frame(title=c("Iliad", "Odyssey"), value=c(-44, -29)),
  data.frame(title=c("Iliad", "Odyssey"), value=c(55, -700))
)

cat(toJSON(x, pretty=TRUE))
```

## Results Required

```
title          A(value)     B(value)     C(value)    
Iliad           -1194           -44          55
Odyssey         -800            -29         -700
```

any one can help me out to get the required results please

Comment: Nice reproducible example! I would encourage you next time to also attempt to describe in words what you want to do.

Comment: You are looking to **join** three dataframes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(tidyr)
unnest(x, points) %>%
    spread(key = term, value = value)
#     title     A   B    C
# 1   Iliad -1194 -44   55
# 2 Odyssey  -800 -29 -700
```

You can, of course, add the the `"(value)"` string into the column names with `paste`. I'll leave that to you (though I think including parentheses in column names is bad idea).

Comment: Thank you Gregor for solution and quick Response

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should also work in `base R`:

```
cbind.data.frame(title=x$points[[1]][,1], 
         do.call(cbind, lapply(1:length(x$term), 
                        function(i) setNames(data.frame(x$points[[i]][,2]), x$term[i]))))

#    title     A   B    C
#1   Iliad -1194 -44   55
#2 Odyssey  -800 -29 -700
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `base R` option with `merge` and `Reduce`

```
setNames(Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = 'title'), x$points), 
                         c('title', as.character(x$term)))
#    title     A   B    C
#1   Iliad -1194 -44   55
#2 Odyssey  -800 -29 -700
```